# Not receiving any callback for synchronized PointCloud2 and Robot EndpointState

Tags: ros, rosmessage, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to receive data from two different publishers as listed below-

1. Message Type: [baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState](http://api.rethinkrobotics.com/baxter_core_msgs/html/msg/EndpointState.html). Topic Name: /robot/limb/right/endpoint_state
2. Message Type: [sensor_msgs::PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html). Topic Name: /kinect2/sd/points

Please see the code snippet below-

```
void DataCollector::callback(const baxter_core_msgs::EndpointStateConstPtr& ee_msg, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& pc_msg)
{
    std::cout << "Solve all of perception here" << std::endl;
}

DataCollector::DataCollector()
{
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    message_filters::Subscriber<baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState> baxter_arm_sub(nh, "/robot/limb/right/endpoint_state", 1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> point_cloud_sub(nh, "/kinect2/sd/points", 1);
    TimeSynchronizer<baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sync(baxter_arm_sub, point_cloud_sub, 100);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&DataCollector::callback, this, _1, _2));
    ros::spin();
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no callback received. I dig into the problem and noticed that `baxter_core_msgs::EndpointState` message is being received in high frequency compared to `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.

Plese see below the screenshot of the output of `rostopic echo /robot/limb/right/endpoint_state|grep secs` and `rostopic echo /kinect2/sd/points|grep secs` in respective terminals taken at the same time-

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282805/not-receiving-any-callback-for-synchronized-pointcloud2-and-robot-endpointstate/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2018-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See #q60903 and #q172676 for almost duplicates.

Summarising: `TimeSynchronizer` needs timestamps to match *exactly*. If you don't have that happening in your message stream, but still want callbacks for messages that are "close enough", then you should use the [ApproximateTimePolicy](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-15**:
Note also that if your Kinect2 is not connected to the Baxter PC, you might want to look into synchronising the clocks between all hosts in your ROS node graph. This will still not make `TimeSynchronizer` call your callbacks, but it will avoid problems later on (with TF fi).

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-02-15**:
Got it. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-15**:
If I may suggest: try to search for these kind of problems. It's not that we don't want to help, but getting answers on this forum takes time, so if you find it yourself, you save time.

Use Google (not the integrated search). I always do something like:

```
$search_term site:answers.ros.org
```

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-02-17**:
Thanks for telling the trick.I got it.